# Python Pandas CSV filter a column with its values N first char

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i'm using pandas csv to work with a huge csv file, basically i have a python script with some args that are filters criteria, one of them is a string that represents a serie of digits (eg: 83351828) and then export the result to a new csv file.
What I want to do is to be able to filter this column by its 4 first char.

### Here is my code :

```
  elif devicePool == '' and css == '' and dirNumber != '' and routePartition == '':
        df = pd.concat(( [chunk[chunk['Directory Number 1'][0:4] == dirNumber] for chunk in pd.read_csv(sourceFile, iterator=True, chunksize=10**4)]))
```

As you can see I used "[0:4]" but it's not working.

```
def main(argv):
    inputfile = ''
    outputfile = ''
    devicePool = ''
    css = ''
    dirNumber = ''
    routePartition = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:p:c:n:r:",["ifile=","ofile=", "dpool=", "css=", "dnumber=", "route="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print('test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile> -p <devicepool> -c <CSS> -n <directorynumber> -r <routepartition>')
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print('test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile> -p <devicepool> -c <CSS> -n <directorynumber> -r <routepartition>')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            outputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-p", "--dpool"):
            devicePool = arg
        elif opt in ("-c", "--css"):
            css = arg
        elif opt in ("-n", "--dnumber"):
            dirNumber = arg
        elif opt in ("-r", "--route"):
            routePartition = arg

    read_CSV(inputfile, outputfile, devicePool, css, dirNumber, routePartition)
```

### Here is the error message :

**pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).**

Comment: What are exactly your inputs and their types? I mean `devicePool`, `css`, `dirNumber`, `routePartition` ?

Comment: Strings, but in this case i'm only using dirNumber which is a string of 4 digits, i want these 4 digits to match with the first 4 digits of the colum "Directory Number 1"

Comment: OK. Those Strings must have been in a matrix. What type of matrix? Array? DataFrame? I suppose you have a DataFrame, do you have a header, I mean column numbers? Which are they? Show the code before, in which you get your variables.

Comment: I don't really know, I'm new to pandas, when I do chunk['Directory Number 1'] == "random string", it works well, that means chunk['Directory Number 1'] is also a string right ?  So why can't I access its first 4 characters with [0:4]

Comment: I edited my post, I simply get those variables with cmd args

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need indexing with `str` for get first 4 letters, also `0` should be omitted:

```
chunk['Directory Number 1'].str[:4]
```

If values are not strings add [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
chunk['Directory Number 1'].astype(str).str[:4]
```